# How can I plot error bars in Mathematica on a bar graph?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, histogram, bar-chart

I'm working with Mathematica and I'm trying to plot a bar graph. I can plot just the bar graph, but I can't get the error bars to work. The only one I can manage to get to work is using  ErrorListPlot, and it graphs it as little points. Ideally, though I'd like it as bars with similar error bars on the top surface. Any thoughts?

This is what I used:

```
ErrorListPlot[list // Transpose,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 230000}}]
```

Again, it just produces points. I've only been able to find a thread to set up the bar graphs with error bars when the error is a function of the data, but I can't seem to get it to work for just a set of data. This is the link to that, and what I (more or less) want it to look like.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/AddErrorBarsToChartsAndPlots.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
ErrorListPlot[{{10, 1}}]
```

first.  Assuming list is just the list of data, you haven't told ErrorListPlot how big to make the error bars, so it just plotted the points.  You need something more like

```
ErrorListPlot[{data, errors} // Transpose, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 230000}}]
```

and you're going to have to compute the errors.  (How would ErrorListPlot[] know the magnitudes of the errors in your list of data?)